# How to assert interface equality without initializing variables?

Tags: typescript, interface, equality

How can I assert that 2 interfaces are identical (duck-typing) without initializing any value?

I use a graphql codegen tool to automatically generate types for graphql queries. 
When I'm querying the same data from various places, I get the same interface generated.
I'd like to consolidate my typing by importing the same interface in all files, while insuring that indeed the different declarations of the interface are identical.

Example:

```
// src/components/__generated__/MyData.ts
export interface MyData_me {
  __typename: "User";
  id: string;
  name: string | null;
  avatarUrl: string | null;
  email: string | null;
}
```

```
// src/models/__generated__/UserData.ts
export interface UserData {
  __typename: "User";
  id: string;
  name: string | null;
  avatarUrl: string | null;
  email: string | null;
}
```

```
// src/models/User.ts
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

import {MyData, MyData_me} from "../components/__generated__/MyData";
import {UserData} from "./__generated__/UserData";

export const UserDataFragment = gql`
  fragment UserData on User {
    id
    name
    avatarUrl
    email
  }
`

if (UserData !== MyData_me) { // [tsserver 2693] [E] 'UserData' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
  throw "We have a problem, interfaces TUser and MyData_me aren't identical!"
}
export type TUser = UserData;
export type TMe = MyData;
```

Is there a clean solution here? Being forced to initialize 2 objects with fake data in order to test `if (typeof user1 !== typeof user2)` sounds wrong since it has nothing to do with my application logic.

Comment: You want to throw a runtime error if two types in TypeScript interfaces not the same?  This is not possible since interfaces are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TS is transpiled to JS.  Do you want a compiler error if two types are not the same?  This *is* possible, more or less.  Do you want me to show you how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I'd like a ts-loader compiler error that would fail the webpack build, if it detects that my interfaces are differents. How would you proceed without adding intermediate objects implementing these interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had two runtime objects and compared them for equality (note that checking `typeof user1 === typeof user2` and `user1 === user2` doesn't count as checking for equality in most cases), it wouldn't tell you whether TypeScript considered them to be of the same type.  For example:

```
const fruit = { apples: 5, oranges: 5 };

interface Apples {
    apples: number;
}
const apples: Apples = fruit; // okay

interface Oranges {
    oranges: number;
}
const oranges: Oranges = fruit; // okay

console.log(JSON.stringify(apples) === JSON.stringify(oranges)); // true
// but Apples and Oranges are not the same type
```

Here, `apples` and `oranges` are identical at runtime, but of different types according to the compiler.  Just because `apples === oranges` it does not mean that `Apples` is `Oranges`.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, by the time JavaScript is running, the entire TypeScript static type system, including all `interface` definitions, has been [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure).  Runtime is too late to catch such an error.

Instead, you can make a compiler error.  Let's define a generic type alias called `MutuallyExtends<T, U>` where `T` and `U` are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to each other.  (Strictly speaking this would be a prohibited circular constraint.  Instead what we can do is introduce a new generic type parameter `V` that [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to whatever is entered for `T`).  It's not exactly true that if `A extends B` and if `B extends A` that `A` is the same type as `B`, but it's pretty close.  There are [stricter checks available](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) but mutual-extends is usually good enough for me.  Anyway, here it is:

```
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = any;
```

The actual value that `MutuallyExtends<T, U>` evaluates to is just `any` and is not what we really care about.  The point is that you can't write `MutuallyExtends<X, Y>` unless the compiler thinks that `X` and `Y` are assignable to each other.

All we have to do is write `MutuallyExtends<MyData_me, UserData>` somewhere in a type position, and see if there's an error.  Like, say this:

```
0 as MutuallyExtends<MyData_me, UserData>; // no error here
```

At runtime that just becomes `0;`, a useless evaluation of `0`.  But what's important is that there's no type error in the compiler.

---

Contrast that with what happens if you used a bad type like

```
interface MyData_Bad {
    _typename: "User"; // wrong number of underscores
    id: string;
    name: string | null;
    avatarUrl: string | null;
    email: string | null;
}

0 as MutuallyExtends<MyData_Bad, UserData>; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'MyData_Bad' does not satisfy the constraint 'UserData'.
//   Property '__typename' is missing in type 'MyData_Bad' but 
//   required in type 'UserData'.
```

Now there's an error that tells you that `MyData_Bad` is incompatible with `UserData`, and even gives some information about why.  This should presumably break your build (or at least spit out a warning during the build) and give you a chance to do something about it before any JavaScript code runs.

---

Anyway, hope that gives you some direction. Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EtYF4YG8YEMAO+ANgKYQBcMArADQwgK5gDmZlVMAvgNwCwAUAJRgoJBHFzASMAIKFSEbAJgq88tjDBIAtgCMxffpwGhIsAsQ1zLizIlRRuMAPTP6Aa1wBPAUJFiJKRgAeUYWMiV+VXow1gpNHX0EQ2N+U2gYpjjKUKyIu2Q0J1cPb1808AgQUgA6IhBmAAoAKQBlYIA5GugEYWYUOC9GiwUAShh0SZg2zu6oXpYBoYY8iFHR4rd5pBIBEt0kWGsFPDAAExDYiNwEaTAQWCgAC2kIXG1pKC98XcE-mHKwlE4kk0gAsl4ACK4KC4AD6H0i0ThcK+PzA7xIlAARABVCBibGGaIoM6UHp9YmqDEfcnzPowAA+CSIRCpKlwADcYTdcQgiHSFswmSy2cpVCRtLgUAKYBSWCKtKyUoD-CCghDobC4QAhXAXLDilSo74kGlYmB4gkIIkuNwAdwQ4GFWj0YnocBgSHOYggoFuECNMFJgspQfNoYVzKVYqiqi5PIQfNl8uF0aQyqDkulKfpUdFKr+QICoJg+LEWtwSNUKLRZsxOPLNvZwbJcrzzBbEfbQsVGdj0QTsKT-MjaYLWalMrHfczRnKdZgYMOSFwrK8AFEAB6ic4QAA8ABUYCQd2azopcXRcSez3uYAA1OgPiYwQ8APlfTC8hgEAAY8EUZcoFXddt13C9901HkERIa9rUrd9Nk0EATwQJ0EBgF5bnKADcCAlc1yITc70g6DtT1M54IrHkkLtNCMIAQj2NwAFp2I4ziuNYz8AD9+IEwSWLfU0YAAcnI+FKLEmAzhACJ7lgN4oBQCBBhgZ5pHSeZpREcSm0rMSamElQAAUnR+BAvnE2tTXNGTVJgbRVIgBlhA00SJKhGDpJgA5YBMmBbgAR1QW4LncxcxIMnkjPKIA)

Comment: I now understand why you asked the runtime vs compile time question in a comment, throw is obviously a command to use only at runtime.

Thanks for the excellent answer. You're awesome!